# Traverse the sub-box of a valid sudoku

Tags: python

I am working on [Valid Sudoku - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/)
and cannot figure out why `box_index = (i // 3 ) * 3 + j // 3` is able to traverse the sub-box

> Determine if a 9x9 Sudoku board is valid. Only the filled cells need to be validated **according to the following rules**:
>
> 1. Each row must contain the digits `1-9` without repetition.
> 2. Each column must contain the digits `1-9` without repetition.
> 3. Each of the 9 `3x3` sub-boxes of the grid must contain the digits `1-9` without repetition.
>
> [image]
>   A partially filled sudoku which is valid.
>
> The Sudoku board could be partially filled, where empty cells are filled with the character `'.'`.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> [
>   ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
>   ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
>   [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
>   ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
>   ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
>   ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
>   [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
>   [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
>   [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
> ]
> Output: true
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> [
>   ["8","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
>   ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
>   [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
>   ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
>   ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
>   ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
>   [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
>   [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
>   [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
> ]
> Output: false
> Explanation: Same as Example 1, except with the 5 in the top left corner being 
>     modified to 8. Since there are two 8's in the top left 3x3 sub-box, it is invalid.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - A Sudoku board (partially filled) could be valid but is not necessarily solvable.
> - Only the filled cells need to be validated according to the mentioned rules.
> - The given board contain only digits `1-9` and the character `'.'`.
> - The given board size is always `9x9`.

Read a clever solution

```
class Solution:
    def isValidSudoku(self, board):
        """
        :type board: List[List[str]]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        # init data
        rows = [{} for i in range(9)]
        columns = [{} for i in range(9)]
        boxes = [{} for i in range(9)]

        # validate a board
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                num = board[i][j]
                if num != '.':
                    num = int(num)
                    box_index = (i // 3 ) * 3 + j // 3

                    # keep the current cell value
                    rows[i][num] = rows[i].get(num, 0) + 1
                    columns[j][num] = columns[j].get(num, 0) + 1
                    boxes[box_index][num] = boxes[box_index].get(num, 0) + 1

                    # check if this value has been already seen before
                    if rows[i][num] > 1 or columns[j][num] > 1 or boxes[box_index][num] > 1:
                        return False         
        return True
```

The TestCase

```
class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
   class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()

    def test_a(self):
        board = [   ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
                    ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
                    [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
                    ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
                    ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
                    ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
                    [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
                    [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
                    [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
                ]
        check = self.solution.isValidSudoku(board)
        self.assertTrue(check)

    def test_b(self):
        board = [   ["8","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
                    ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
                    [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
                    ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
                    ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
                    ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
                    [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
                    [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
                    [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
                ]
        check = self.solution.isValidSudoku(board)
        self.assertFalse(check)

unittest.main() def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()

    def test_a(self):
        board = [   ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
                    ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
                    [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
                    ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
                    ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
                    ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
                    [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
                    [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
                    [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
                ]
        check = self.solution.isValidSudoku(board)
        self.assertTrue(check)

    def test_b(self):
        board = [   ["8","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
                    ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
                    [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
                    ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
                    ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
                    ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
                    [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
                    [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
                    [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
                ]
        check = self.solution.isValidSudoku(board)
        self.assertFalse(check)

unittest.main()
```

Could you please provide any hints why `box_index = (i // 3 ) * 3 + j // 3` can traverse the sub-box?

Comment: tl;dr - what do you mean by "traverse the sub-box"? AFAICT the expression works out which sub-box (0-8) the cell (i,j) is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the the whole box in to `3*3` sub-box, `(i, j)` is belongs to the sub-boxs which index is `(i//3, j//3)`, this is a `3*3` 2d-array. if we want to flatten it into a `1*9` 1d-array, the index will be `(i // 3 ) * 3 + j // 3`.

sub-boxs with index:

```
|0|1|2|
|3|4|5|
|6|7|8|
```

If you are still confused, you can try some examples, and figure it out.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )